# Free hosting of shapefiles to make an interactive map?

Tags: shapefile, web-mapping

What is a free site where I can upload shapefiles and make my own interactive map to share with others by a link?

Comment: You tagged this question with [tag:flexviewer] and [tag:GeoWebCache] -- are you specifically interested in Flex and/or Java, or were you just looking for tags also related to web-mapping?

Comment: Does the information in any of these help answer your Question, or are they too specific? [1](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24213/looking-for-a-free-cloud-based-web-mapping-stack-host)  [2](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/how-to-start-web-mapping)  [3](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74600/whats-the-most-appropriate-toolset-for-creating-a-community-map)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a free public account on ArcGIS.com. From there, you can upload your shapefile(s) (provided that they contain fewer than 1000 features), create maps containing your shapefiles, and share your maps with others via URL.

Answer (score 2):

If you are into open source, you can also use [CartoDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CartoDB), which allows you to import shapefiles as well as use other GIS formats. Quoting wikipedia:

> CARTO (formerly CartoDB) is a Software as a Service (SaaS) cloud
>   computing platform that provides GIS and web mapping tools for display
>   in a web browser

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with some styling issues, you can save the shapefiles as KML and upload them to MyMaps on Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

I've been worked with ArcGIS Online having a free public account. There you can upload the shapefiles and then you can share the link with your customers, friends, colleagues etc.